# How do I revert the changes made by a specific user?

Tags: views, 6

I want to revert the changes made by a specific admin user in Drupal 6.37. In all the pages that I want to revert, the create new revision box was not selected. Hence, I have no way of finding out the changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have revisions you can't rollback the changes unless you have a database backups that you can use to restore and old copy of your site.

If you don't have any strategy to save your database you can consider use the [Backup and Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module, for Drupal 6 the last release is the [6.x-2.8](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate/releases/6.x-2.8)

> Back up and restore your Drupal MySQL database, code, and files or
>   migrate a site between environments. Backup and Migrate supports gzip,
>   bzip and zip compression as well as automatic scheduled backups.